# Vue.js v-bind with v-html

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've to bind a `textarea` with `vue` and it has to be rendered in html.

I already tried this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" v-model="content" v-html="content"></textarea>
```

That's not working. Is this even possible?

Thanks

**Code:**

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 margin__top__small">
            <div v-if="editing">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" v-model="content"></textarea>
                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" @click="update">Update</button>
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-link" @click="editing = false">Annuleer</button>
            </div>

            <div v-else v-html="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you planning to edit? i suggest using a div for displaying html, and onclick show the textarea.

Comment: Please see my edit above. @GerardoRosciano

Comment: No, it's not possible render HTML in the value for a textarea. You could possibly use a `contenteditable` DIV though. Here there be dragons. I would suggest you find a nice control.